# import names into Firstname and lastname textfields by clicking on "browse names" button using java

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets

[image]
I am new with java and jsp and servlets. I want to browse Firstname and Lastname by using "Browse Name" button instead of typing whole name. I was thinking like I will put "Browse Name" button in front of Firstname textfield. Then user will click on it and select his name from list( i.e. user will select his/her name from excel file). I don't know this import/browse names from excel way will work or not. Is there any other way to do it?? Please suggest me. Thanks in advance. :)

```html
<tr>
  <td>First Name</td>
  <td>
    <input list="firstnamelist" required="" name="firstname" />
    <datalist id="firstnamelist">
         <option value="abc">
         <option value="xyz">
         <option value="pqr">
         <option value="abcde">
         <option value="asdf">
    </datalist>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: someone please help :)

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this

- you can convert the excel sheet to database

npm install mysql --save (install mysql dependencies)

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var respo;
var con = mysql.createConnection({
host: "localhost",
user: "root",
password: "madmax",
database: "employees"
});

con.connect(function(err) {
if (err) throw err;
con.query("SELECT DISTINCT first_name FROM employees", function (err, 
result, fields) {
if (err) throw err;
respo=result
console.log(respo);
});
});
```

this will give you all the distinct first_names from the database

create dynamic select drop-down menu in html for the response using loop statements.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form id="form">
<select id="fname">

</select>
</form>
<br>
</body>

<script>
let i;
for(i=0;i<3;i++){
document.getElementById("fname").innerHTML+=`<option value="${}">${} 
</option>`
}
</script>
</html>
```

${} try to check the response before adding value in it from the console...

${respo.first_name} like this

now fetch the selected response from first_name and last_name by the user and then send response accordingly from the database.

Answer (score 0):

So your database is in excel or mysql? If it is in excel then you can explore POI to export data from excel file to your program. Load the list of First and Last name in a Set object to avoid duplicate and populate the dropdowns with values from the Set objects

Comment: @NorhingBox My database is in MySQL. I have recently added above code into my html code and I have given sample options in datalist. But firstname list count will be more so it doesn't look good. So I want to hide other name options from list. then how to do it??

Comment: What do you mean by "hide other name options from the list". What exactly do you wanna show and what do you want to hide?

Comment: I have added only five name options i.e. abc,xyz,pqr,abcde and asdf  in my drop down list. But there will be more(may be more than 1000) options in dropdown list. So it doesn't looks good GUI. So I want to show only some options and other should be hidden from user. We can also use "More" option in drop down list but I don't know how to implement it.

Comment: please see my above comment

Comment: In your mysql select query, you can add limit and offset. Everytime you click more, you just need to change the offset. Limit will be constant. The drawback however is that you won't be able to go back to the previous list.